# How do I pass a string from html form, through a router in order to generate and store an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, input, body-parser

I am trying to pass a string from the frontend into the backend, but I have hit a roadblock. I am using Node, Express, Body Parser, EJS, and PostgreSQL. My basic file system is this:

```
– app
   |– api
   |   |– thing.js
   |
   |– index.js

– views
   |– pages
       |– index.ejs
```

I have a form submission in index.ejs that passes data to the index.js file:

index.ejs

```
<form action="/creatething" method="post">
       <h1>Make a thing</h1>
       <p> What is your thing called?
       <input name="wtitle" type="text">
       </p>
       <p> What is your name?
       <input name="cuser" type="text">
       </p>

       <input type="submit"  value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

The above code triggers /creatething, which is placed in index.js

index.js

```
    const express = require ('express');
    const thingRouter = require('./api/thing');
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const app = express();

    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
    app.use('/thing', thingRouter);
    app.get('/', function (req, res){
        res.render('pages/index');
    });


    app.post('/creatething',(req,res)=>{
        console.log('clicked '+ req.body);
    });
    module.exports= app;
```

With this I am able to create a message in the console that prints the user input from the form. However, I am trying to send this data to a database through code in thing.js:

thing.js

```
const {Router} = require('express');
const router = new Router();

router.get('/',(req,res)=> {
    console.log(req.body);
    // Placeholder for working code that stores thing in database :)
});

module.exports = router;
```

The problem here is that I don't know how to pass the req.body data from the index.js file to the thing.js method that inserts the data into the database. I could just add the database code into the index.js file, but I was trying to keep things more separated and learn about routing/mounting. What am I missing at this point?

Comment: Why do you using Router inside thing.js?

Comment: @Mayur I was mostly following along with a tutorial that was using Router, but I guess I can't really pass data through a router, only get the information it provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change a few things in your `thing.js` file. Only few lines of code is required instead of importing `Router` from express and add some extra routes.

Just copy below code and paste to your respective files.

`thing.js`

```
const get = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
}

module.exports = get;
```

`index.js`

```
const express = require ('express');
const get = require('./api/things');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.render('pages/index');
});


app.post('/creatething', (req,res)=>{
    get(req,res);
});
app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('App is running on port: 4000');
});
module.exports= app;
```

Hope this helps you solve the issue.

Comment: Anytime Man!! ;)